# UIImage View does not display in launch storyboard iOS 8

Tags: ios8, storyboard, launchimage

I am trying to create a launch storyboard for an iOS 8.1 app using Xcode 6.1.1

If i create a ViewController, add a view and add a label to that view, it all seems to work fine on actual devices. But when I add a UIImageView with an image file, the image never appears on the device.

Has anyone else had this problem? Has anyone else been successful just having a simple UIImage in a launch storyboard? I must be missing something.

FGRios

Comment: Where is UIImageView added?Can you put some code here?

Comment: It is all done through Interface Builder. I am trying to create a Launch storyboard rather than use individual launch images.

Answer (score 4):

Just use image file added to project, not from *.xcassets

[image: Just use image file added to project]

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue. Removing the app from my phone, reboot the phone, and reinstalling the app fixed it for me.

Comment: still happening. this worked to fix for me. so annoying.